# CreateProcess "cmd.exe /c" with output redirection

Tags: cmd, io-redirection, createprocess

I wrote a shell GUI application that starts a console application with `CreateProcessW`, then terminates and leaves the console application running.

Now I would like to turn on the debug output of the console application and redirect its output to a file.

I could organize pipes to redirect the output, but I want that the GUI application terminates and leaves things alone. So I decided to launch `cmd.exe` and use its standard redirection symbols:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\ConsoleProgram\ConsoleProgram.exe" -debug > "R:\log.txt" 2>&1
```

It writes to the `log.txt` file:

> "C:\Program" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

When I use "/C/Program Files (x86)/ConsoleProgram/ConsoleProgram.exe" instead, it writes:

> system could not find the path specified

Comment: I suggest to use `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\ConsoleProgram\ConsoleProgram.exe" -debug > "R:\log.txt" 2>&1"` whereby `C:\Windows` should not be hard-coded in the GUI application, but should be the string value of the predefined Windows environment variable `SystemRoot` which is concatenated with the remaining entire command line string. If the environment variable `SystemRoot` is very unlikely not defined, there should be used as fallback the string `C:\Windows` and hope this is the correct path to Windows directory.

Comment: Well, there could be used also the string value of the environment variable `ComSpec` to get the fully qualified file name of the command interpreter., but that is not as safe/secure as the usage of `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` because of `ComSpec` is an environment variable which can be easily modified as defined as __system__ environment variable. Run `cmd /?` in a command prompt window for the meaning of switch `/D` (ignore `AutoRun`), `/S` (old-style command line) and why there is one more `"` at beginning and at end of the command line to execute by `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **-debug** inside the double quotes.
Everything else seems to be correct in your script.

Instead of this

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\ConsoleProgram\ConsoleProgram.exe" -debug > "R:\log.txt" 2>&1
```

modify as shown below:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\ConsoleProgram\ConsoleProgram.exe -debug" > "R:\log.txt" 2>&1
```

Note: This will not work since it is Unix style: "/C/Program Files (x86)/ConsoleProgram/ConsoleProgram.exe"

Comment: `Note: This will not work since it is Unix style` - what do you exactly mean with this?

Comment: What I meant is; in Unix/Linux OS the directory separator is "/" whereas in Windows, it is "\". So when you gave the path using a forward slash in Command prompt (cmd.exe), it will not recognise it.

However, this style can be used in Unix terminal emulators for Windows such as Cygwin.

Comment: I didn't invent this syntax by myself. There was an advice to use it with intention that it would fix the problem.